# How can I fix Ansible's hashi_vault lookup despite installed hashivault collection and hvac package?

Tags: ansible, python-venv, hashicorp-vault, ansible-galaxy

I need to debug a problem related to community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault lookup in ansible. I've installed everything needed - i.e hashivault galaxy collection & hvac python package - and yet, when I run the lookup - the playbook complains that I don't have the package and i should installed it.

Ansible runs on venv:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8  -m venv playbook/env
```

different debug outputs:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.16

pip show hvac
Name: hvac
Version: 1.1.0
Summary: HashiCorp Vault API client
Home-page: https://github.com/hvac/hvac
Author: Ian Unruh
Author-email: ianunruh@gmail.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /root/playbook/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pyhcl, requests
Required-by:

ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.10]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /root/playbook/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /root/playbook/env/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.16 (default, Mar 10 2023, 03:07:59) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True

ansible -m debug -a 'var=ansible_python_interpreter' localhost
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_python_interpreter": "/root/playbook/env/bin/python3.8"
}

ansible -m debug -a 'var=ansible_playbook_python' localhost
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_playbook_python": "/root/playbook/env/bin/python3.8"
}

ansible-galaxy collection list | grep hashi
# /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
[...]
community.hashi_vault 5.0.0
```

lookup that fails:

```
consul_gossip_key: "{{ lookup('community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault', 'secret=secret_path url=vault_url').data.gossip_key }}"
```

Error:

```
TASK [consul : consul | Configure Consul] **************************************
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'template'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message:An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault', 'secret/data/some_path url=https://vault.url').data.gossip_key }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Please pip install hvac to use the hashi_vault lookup module.. Please pip install hvac to use the hashi_vault lookup module.. An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault', 'secret/data/some_path url=https://vault.url').data.gossip_key }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Please pip install hvac to use the hashi_vault lookup module.. Please pip install hvac to use the hashi_vault lookup module."}
```

Edit: Also worth mentioning that it's failing only in arm64 AmazonLinux2 AMIs, while on an x86 CentOS AMI - the playbook runs smoothly, including the lookup

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip show hvac` yields the same as  `pip show hvac`?

Comment: Yes. it yields the same as `pip show hvac`

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: I had the same, the OS updated, the python version updated and the VENV symbolic links did not update. Also all the obvious check points for VENV need to gone through... did you activate it... etc